# Error out of disk, grub rescue

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu via usb with no problems, but when I restart, I get an error message:

```
error out of disk" 'grub rescue.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be you are out of disk space.Boot from a live cd and post the output of **sudo df -h** also post the results of [bootscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Also see [How do I investigate boot and partition issues?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this error occurs when GRUB can't find a usable grub.cfg. Since the boot configuration isn't there, GRUB drops you to the grub-rescue prompt. Following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue%20Mode) you should be able to boot Ubuntu.

Once you've booted Ubuntu, reinstall GRUB2 by running

```
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub2
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be searching for a solution: I had this problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 on my HP nc6400 laptop. The problem was solved by installing Ubuntu via the alternate installation cd. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like you have made a partition for the install files that is small enough that is is getting the messages Ubuntu added to make users aware of running out of space. It shouldn't hurt anything unless the OS grows beyond the amount of extra you have. The simple solution is to install GParted found in the Ubuntu Software-Center. You can simply drag the portion used as the swap space to make it a little bigger and stop the warnings. It's best to do it soon since there's always a small possibility of data loss when changing partition  sizes.