# "can't read file" error after installation causes system to not boot

Tags: boot, installation

i have recently installed ubuntu 11.10 on my system along with windows xp.

Previously i have ubuntu 9.04, i have deleted those partitions and installed 11.10.

installation is complete but i am unable to boot into ubuntu. Following is the error.

```
error: can't read file
error: load kernel first.
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this could be a boot issue, can you [look at this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues) to get the information we need and then edit it into your question? Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error, also with 11.10 and WinXP.  I reinstalled ubuntu but this time did manual partitioning, just a single partition mounted at /, plus a swap partition.  That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you are getting are non-specific.

You can try two things.

First, and perhaps easiest, would be to try to run boot repair. Boot a live, desktop CD, open a terminal, and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image: boot-repair]

For additional information see - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Your second option is to run the `boot_info_script`

You download the script and run it, paste the link back here and we can help debug.

For details see [How do I investigate boot and partition issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues)