# How do I report a bug that happens during boot?

Tags: boot, bug-reporting

I seem to have found a bug in 12.04 while it's booting, but all the questions on this site seem to point users to [reporting bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) once the desktop is up and running by using `ubuntu-bug`.

How do I report a bug where I can't use `ubuntu-bug` and where I don't know the package name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [finding the right package page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage):

> During boot If you encounter a bug with the boot splash screen
>   (typically an Ubuntu logo displayed during boot), the package is:
>
> `plymouth` since 10.04 Lucid Lynx If the screen goes blank after the
>   splash screen (about the time the login screen should come up), report
>   the bug against `xorg`.
>
> If the boot errors or freezes even in "recovery mode", the bug should
>   be reported against the kernel.

See also:

- [How do I investigate boot and partition issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues)

for more things you can add to the bug report.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Just reported the problem under plymouth.