# XPS 9310 Developer Edition not booting when connected to WD19TB dock

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell, xps, thunderbolt

When the [XPS 9310 DE laptop](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/new-xps-13-developer-edition/spd/xps-13-9310-laptop) (using pre-installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Dell with all updates, including LVFS updates for laptop and dock) is powered off and connected to the [WD19TB](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-thunderbolt-dock-wd19tb/apd/210-arik/pc-accessories) docking station, it will not boot when I power it on.

When I press the power button (on the laptop or dock) the screen on the laptop becomes active, shows a dell logo, but just stays stuck that way indefinitely.

If I press and hold the power button for 10+ seconds the computer can be forcefully shut down. When I start it up again after forcing it down I then see the Dell logo, but the computer continues where the next screen I see is a GRUB boot menu. From there I can choose "Ubuntu" and the computer boots normally with no problems.

Another way to make everything work is before booting the computer, unplug the Thunderbolt cable from the laptop. Then it boots up normally and I can connect the Thunderbolt cable again and things work normally from there.

I am seeking a solution so I always can leave the laptop connected to the docking station and have it boot up normally on the first attempt (no forced shutdowns or having disconnect/reconnect things).

I've looked for dmsg or syslogs, but don't see anything, which kind of makes sense since it's not getting very far. I'd appreciate any ideas for fixing this or even just alternative debugging methods.

update: My issue is very similar to what's seen in [this Dell forum thread](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Precision-5540-WD19TB-dock-Ubuntu-20-04-won-t-boot/td-p/7597259).

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119443/how-do-i-report-a-bug-that-happens-during-boot) for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks @user68186. I've opened a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1906857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue ended up being resolved by a [separate bug fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.6/+bug/1902469) and a new kernel release. I can confirm that this resolves the issue for me.

Basics from that bug report:

```
[Impact]
The machine connect with the external monitor on dock(Thunderbolt),
Then system would hang during the boot-up.

[Fix]
The atomic check hooks must look up the encoder to be used with a
connector from the connector's atomic state, and not assume that it's
the connector's current attached encoder. The latter one can change
under the atomic check func, or can be unset yet as in the case of MST
connectors.
```