# Why does Windows 7 overall performance is better than Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, boot, nvidia

I have a **Intel i7 2600** processor, 8GB DDR3 RAM, nVidia GTX570 graphics card, and still Ubuntu taking 45-50 seconds to boot and 32-35 seconds to power off, while Windows 7 boots in only 20-25 seconds and shuts down in 10 seconds. Both OS has Automatic Login  enabled, and obviously I am dual-booting.

Ubuntu is slow in Pre loading stage too, and doesn't show any boot splash after installing drivers and didn't recognize my nVidia graphics card on jockey GTK, I had to add "x swat" repository and that didn't worked. I installed proprietary drivers through terminal (`nvidia-common`, `nvidia-settings`) in order to have 3D acceleration. But it doesn't make any difference on the speed.

I also have a Pentium 4 PC and in that PC, Ubuntu 11.10 is way faster than windows 7 or XP with nvidia graphics card. And Preload (showing splash screen) is good.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/924890/) is my boot script, some words there are in Spanish because my Ubuntu is in Spanish lanuage.

I am not using WUBI, Ubuntu has its own partition, it is 64-bits, and Matlab 2011 has very low performance compared to Windows version.

Comment: It looks like this could be a boot issue, can you [look at this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues) to get the information we need and then edit it into your question? Thanks!

Comment: it is not a straight forward question. Boot can be delay for several resion. As an example if you are using squid3 then computer takes 30+ seconds to shutdown. Because squid3 takes 30s(default) to shutdown. So System will not shutdown before squid3 stop. Find out, why does boot take time. While booting (ubuntu logo) press up key, it will show booting process details.

Comment: Maybe to look for the issue you could also be interested in bootchart: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting

Comment: post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: If you are using Wubi to run Ubuntu then you will see some performance issues.  To get around this simply stop using Wubi and install Ubuntu on its own partition.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 64 bits or 32 bits version? because I have experienced a lot of performance problems with 64 bits version...

Comment: WUBI always have low performance and it doesn't show the true power of ubuntu. You will see degraded performance! It is best if you install it alongside your Windows and do a dual boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have a Core i7 2600 with 16GB RAM running Ubuntu 11.10 (32Bit+PAE). The motherboard is an Intel DZ68DB and an Nvidia 440 GT. The booting time is about 20-25 seconds on Ubuntu 11.10, but on Windows 7 it gets up to a minute easily.

Basically this depends a lot on the motherboard, not just the CPU or Memory. But in your case and mine we need to remember that **Sandy Bridge (And Ivy Bridge) is not well supported in 11.10**. In 12.04 you should see a change. There are many questions in askubuntu about the problems with Sandy Bridge that are already solved in the latest kernel (And applied in 12.04).

I can vouch that the some weird stuff does happen every so often like the system freezes sometimes for a second or that it gets just weird when doing several activities. But for what I have been following on omgubuntu, phoronix, and the H the next Ubuntu version will solve most if not all problems related to Sandy/Ivy. So you can expect a better boot time and a better response time in general with that hardware.

Only 2 weeks to go for 12.04.

Comment: You were right. Now it is a little bit slower than Windows 7. My performance has improved with 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 11.10 is an extreme exception in Ubuntu versions, and it is slower than other versions. It's a version in the middle of a large transition between platforms.

My advise is to upgrade to 12.04 as soon as you feel comfortable with it. It's really very much faster, consumes a lot less power, and therefore is also much more quiet. In general; 12.04 is what you should want. It'll be released in less than two weeks, on Thursday 26th.

Answer (score 0):

How many cores does ubuntu see in your CPU?  I have a dual core i7, but ubuntu can see only one core.  If you have the same situation, then it is understandable for ubuntu being slower than w7.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why someone would down vote my comment here?  I was try to help around here. :(

Comment: I can see all of them (8 cores) with hardinfo, but all of them are in 1000MHz. And it is 3400MHz on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As much as everyone here would like to help, I think the askers question may be outside the scope of reasonable. Perhaps better to ask multiple specific questions like `How can I increase my boot speed?`.

https://askubuntu.com/faq

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you dual boot Windows and Ubuntu(Or any other Linux) on two different partition and use O&O Defrag to analyst the drives. You can see the one with Ubuntu is horribly fragmented and locked(Unable to defragment). So if you keep defragment every week on your HDD which installed Windows, Windows boot faster.

*Ubuntu always faster than Windows when you are using a SSD. SSD no need to defragment because it use different technology to read and write, it doesn't matter of a file placed in a thousand places.