# Why does Ubuntu occasionally  not start?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, startup, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Why is it happening that sometimes, for apparently no reason, Ubuntu refuses to start, and only rarely it does?

Sometimes, Ubuntu simply doesn't start! After I select Ubuntu in the pink screen, it shows a black one where nothing appears and a "_" blinks on the top-left corner. Also, sometimes (everytime the netbook is not connected to the power) it shows a lot of text on this black screen like when it is loading but then the screen gets all weird full of dots and senseless things everywhere (it's not text) and then frezes... looks like my mega drive when it "tilts" :S Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues and add that info to your question.

Comment: Mine was doing this up until yesterday. Select recovery mode from the boot manager menu, then update from there. My graphics drivers were the cause.