# Booting Ubuntu from 2nd Hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I Just bought a Refurbished Dell precision M6600, Which has two 700GB 7200RPM Hard Drives. Windows is Installed on the first, Ubuntu on the second (Along with Swap Partition). Everytime I've done this (Probably 2 dozen times), after I install Ubuntu, and Change Bios Settings (to boot ubuntu HD first), It typically boots into grub to give me he option of Booting into either OS Partition.

But This time is different. It won't boot into grub. I've tried changing boot sequence to boot Ubuntu HD, but it still boots straight into Windows. I've even tried Disabling the Windows Hard Drive (In BIOS), so it only has the option of booting the Ubuntu HD, but SOMEHOW it still boots straight into Windows. I would go and just disconnect the Windows Hard drive, but I really don't feel like tearing apart my new laptop. If troubleshooting comes down to it, I gotta do what I gotta do. But I really don't feel like going thru that trouble.

I can only seem to boot the Live CD (actually live USB, Created with Universal USB Installer). I've already re-formatted and re-installed Ubuntu 3 times Trying to troubleshoot, to no avail...

Just to be sure, Grub should be installed on the Ubuntu HD during installation, not the Windows HD correct? That's the only thing I feel like I haven't tried.

I guess my question here is, What would be the reasons it is booting into Windows no matter what I try??

Comment: Is this a UEFI machine?  You'd need an EFI partition for the shim/grub bootloaders on the second disk in that case.

Comment: In case you feel like adding some technical info to the question, please check out [boot info](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues). I am not sure the question is answerable as is.

Comment: Mike's link is to bootinfoscript which I still use. But now use a fork as original is not maintained. https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript But the forked version is also now part of Boot-Repair's Summary Report and that includes some extra info, also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation – the accepted answer includes a short explanation of the boot drive setting.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, after digging thru all of the Links Posted to me here, The answer to my question (Just to be sure, Grub should be installed on the Ubuntu HD during installation, not the Windows HD correct?) and solution to my problem is:

Yes. Install GRUB onto the Windows Partition. So if you're having this same issue and have tried everything except for installing GRUB onto your Windows HD, Try that. It's exactly what worked for me.

Thanks for your help and links everyone!