# Long boot Ubuntu 18

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, crash

Relatively (3 months old) fresh install and noticed long boot times since start.

Lately since i did a driver install, i been seeing a message during boot; something along the lines of `kernel crash` with a whole list of other output with green checkmarks.

it seems the more problematic longer boottimes started when i did : `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

I already did some research and found a couple things, such as:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/90046 , where my output is the following:
  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CW84Gy77ZQ/
- `systemd-analyze blame`, output: https://pastebin.com/0p5FHdw7

Output of screen:
[crash boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEuhc.png)

output of: `systemd-analyze critical-chain` :

```
graphical.target @39.565s
└─multi-user.target @39.565s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @36.899s +123ms
    └─snapd.service @28.442s +8.454s
      └─basic.target @27.569s
        └─sockets.target @27.569s
          └─snapd.socket @27.540s +28ms
            └─sysinit.target @27.540s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @27.178s +361ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @26.890s +251ms
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @3.682s +23.206s
                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.026s +392ms
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @3.021s
                        └─system.slice @3.020s
                          └─-.slice @3.017s
```

Any idea what i could try for my next step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` where is the output of that?

Comment: You wrote "something along the lines of kernel crash with a whole list of other output " -- it may help to know precisely what that error message was. If it is only shown for a short time, you could take a photo using a smartphone or something in irder not to lose sight of the error message.

Comment: @Rinzwind, blame output: https://pastebin.com/0p5FHdw7

Comment: @Elias added the boot screen output

Comment: But that "crash boot screen" picture does not look like a crash, it looks like things are working. Do you mean that it hangs at that point?

Comment: @Elias you are right, but before i never saw this screen, and from start to finish the boot time takes 2 minutes (which seems really long)!

Comment: Check if the UUIDs are correct (blkid and fstab entries). To get a faster startup, offen it helps to disabled the plymouth ("sudo nano /etc/default/grub" -> change line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d" -> update grub with "sudo update-grub" -> restart; the part "video=SVIDEO-1:d" depends on your system.