# get error on boot - fresh install

Tags: mediaserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error out of disk, grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18531/error-out-of-disk-grub-rescue)

I just loaded Ubuntu 11.10 as a fresh install.

I am getting a error "HD0 out of disk", press any key to continue".  The system seems to still load fine. I just don't like getting errors even before the boot.