# error: out of disk message after fresh install of 11.10

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error out of disk, grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18531/error-out-of-disk-grub-rescue)

After installing 11.10 I get an error: out of disk message followed by grub2 rescue>.  This happens on the first restart at the end of the installation.  I new to ubuntu so I would very much appreciate some help...

thanks much