# error: hd0 out of disk?

Tags: grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Samsung Chronos 7 laptop. The computer was running fine, until recently after a required reboot, the screen was black showing:

"error: hd0 out of disk
grub rescue>"

I have absolutely NO IDEA what's going on here AT ALL. I've read that it has to do with conflicting partitions, but I'm 99% sure that I deleted the entire hard drive of any existing partition when first installing Ubuntu. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18531/error-out-of-disk-grub-rescue

Comment: Thanks for the link, though I don't see how I can get into Ubuntu through grubrescue, let alone install Grub2.

Comment: You 1st need to follow the link in the top answer.

Comment: I still can't find anything. All I can see is updating Grub while inside Ubuntu, or from some other menu. I am REALLY confused right now...

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Have you tried booting a live system? It will provide the tools you need for the rescue.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's sad that peaple hardly ever seem to pick an answer for their question -- this way, the whole "duplicate" idea is getting messed up.

Comment: Haven't tried that. Is there a specific process in doing that?